# Add google maps event listener to close button in InfoWindows to show alert

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I want to make alert when `close` button in `infowindow` clicked.

I tried make `addListener` `closeclick` event, but the alert is not showing.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(info1, "closeclick", function(){
      alert("closed"); 
      console.log("alert show");
});
```

I also tried `console.log` in code above, but it's not show anything

Here's the full code

```
var lat = -6.121435,
    lng = 106.774124,
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var mmm;
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
        }
        
    },
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: true });

var info1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); 

//to show info window and marker
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dblclick", function (e) { 
        
    placeMarker(e.latLng);
});

//code to show alert
google.maps.event.addListener(info1, "closeclick", function(){
      alert("closed"); 
      console.log("alert show");
});

function placeMarker(location) {
  const contentString = 
       '<p style="text-align: center;margin-top:15px;margin-right:10px;">'+
              'Here is your marker'+
       '</p>';
  info1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: contentString,
     maxWidth: 350,
     maxHeight: 150
  });
        
  if (mmm == null) {
     mmm = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: location,
       map: map,
       icon: blue
     });
  } else {
     mmm.setPosition(location);
  }
  info1.open(map, mmm);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Why are you declaring `info1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow` twice? What have you tried to fix the issue? What does your Javascript console say?

Comment: You edited now and added *Here's the full code* but this is obviously **not** the full code. I see no map declaration, I still cannot tell when the various bits of code you shared are executed, etc. Again, you need to provide a [mcve] << please do read that link!

Comment: I get a Javascript error when running the code you provided `Uncaught ReferenceError: mmm is not defined`. Have you looked at the Javascript console and have you tried debugging? When I fix this error, I get a second error `ReferenceError: blue is not defined` ...

Comment: I'm forget to put `var mmm`; in the code. I've fixed it

Comment: The issue is what I mentioned in my first comment. You are creating a new Infowindow object twice (once when the map loads and once every time you get to the `placeMarker()` function. You should use the `setContent()` method of the Infowindow instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the issues mentioned in the comments on your question, it works as expected.

Please see the comments in the code for what I have modified. I also removed the `icon: blue` which was undefined.

```js
function initialize() {

  var lat = -6.121435,
    lng = 106.774124,
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  var mmm = null; // Declare mmm variable (null)

  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      fullscreenControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true, // Moved this line here and remove the setOptions() which has the same effect
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
      }
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var info1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 350, // Moved this here
    maxHeight: 150 // Moved this here
  });

  //to show info window and marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng);
  });

  //code to show alert
  google.maps.event.addListener(info1, "closeclick", function() {
    alert("closed");
    console.log("alert show");
  });

  function placeMarker(location) {
    const contentString =
      '<p style="text-align: center;margin-top:15px;margin-right:10px;">' +
      'Here is your marker' +
      '</p>';

    info1.setContent(contentString); // Use the setContent method instead of creating another Infowindow object

    if (mmm == null) {
      mmm = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
      });
    } else {
      mmm.setPosition(location);
    }
    info1.open(map, mmm);
  }
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```